# Unable to log on to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, password

I am not an Ubuntu power user, but years ago opted for this over Windows and never regretted it.

Recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18 and all was fine until this morning. Logged in first thing, did some work, logged out. Came back later to log in but repeatedly being told password is incorrect. Have restarted multiple times. Can't even log in through the tty.

Please help. I need to get month-end invoices out urgentlyand am now dead in the water.

Comment: Test for keyboard function: When you login, each keypress makes a dot in the password field. Are your keypresses making dots? Is *every* character in your password making a dot? (count them)

Comment: Hello Jan please be more detailed in the time frame between 'Logged in first thing, did some work, logged out.'. Please discribe or try to remember what happend during ' did some work'.

Comment: Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F3` and see if you can log into the console. This will tell us if your User ID / Password are invalid or if the  GUI Login screen is broken.

Comment: Also in the GUI next to then `Sign In` button there is a gear. After entering your password but before pressing `Enter` key, click the gear and make sure `Unity` is selected.

Comment: Also I think there used to be a bug that after one bad password spelling all correct attempts after were also called invalid. In this case you need to reboot.

Answer (score 3):

## Console access has changed in 18.04

You converted from 16.04 to 18.04 and cannot log into TTY. See this: [How do I switch between console mode and GUI in 17.10 and newer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979027/how-do-i-switch-between-console-mode-and-gui-in-17-10-and-newer)

- In **16.04** you could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for **console** (as you call `tty`) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for **GUI**.
- In **18.04** pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> brings up the **GUI** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> brings up the **console** (tty).

---

## Four new Desktop environments were added in 18.04

When upgrading **16.04** to **18.04** you can get five different sign in options for different desktop environments:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 five desktops.jpg]

- Key in your password but **do not press** <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click the gear icon next to the <kbd>Sign In</kbd> button.
- The drop down menu pictured above will now appear.
- When upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 you'll want to select the highlighted option **Unity**
- The drop down menu will close and now you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the password to be accepted.

---

## Invalid password login loop in 18.04

There was a bug where if you entered the password incorrectly the first time, you could not successfully enter it until rebooting:

- May 06, 2018 - [Can't login on 18.04 after entering wrong password](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1769416)
- April 19, 2018 - [(regression) Ubuntu 18.04 login screen rejects a valid password on first attempt (if starting with Shift key). Usually works on the second attempt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1765261)
- July 25, 2018 - [Ubuntu 18.04 on login loop, even with correct password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059458/ubuntu-18-04-on-login-loop-even-with-correct-password)