# Conky starts, but doesn't display (21.10)

Tags: conky

Was running 20.04 and conky worked fine.  Double upgraded to 21.10 and now after reboot there's no conky display. I have it as a Startup Application as "conky -p 30". A 'ps' shows that indeed /usr/bin/conky is running, and if I touch my .conkyrc file, then the display shows.

Any suggestions?

Update: I upgrade another box from 20.04 to 21.10 and conky does the same thing - I can see it running but until I touch the .conkyrc file, there is no display

Comment: Maybe a wayland issue, try Xorg session instead.

Comment: Sorry, please explain more

Comment: @LarryM See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069530/unable-to-log-on-to-18-04/1069579#1069579

Comment: 21.10 doesn't seem to have that option at login