# ZFS rpool fails to mount on boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, root, zfs

My system was booting fine, but I was trying to resolve a couple ZFS related boot errors that said:

```
cannot mount '/root': directory is not empty
cannot mount '/var/cache': directory is not empty
```

In my infinite wisdom, I added "rpool/var/cache /var/cache zfs defaults 0 0" to my fstab, and my system failed to reboot and it kicked me to terminal where I was able to remove that line from fstab and reboot my system. Here's the current state of /etc/fstab:

```
rpool/var/log /var/log zfs defaults 0 0
rpool/var/tmp /var/tmp zfs defaults 0 0
/dev/zvol/rpool/swap none swap defaults 0 0
```

One weird thing, after it rebooted, it was stuck in a login loop and I had to go to terminal and chown my `username` folder in the home directory per [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059458/ubuntu-18-04-on-login-loop-even-with-correct-password).

Now rpool will not mount and, as a result, my folders are missing from my home directory, along with all my files, since a lot of my system folders are inherited from rpool. Here is what my ZFS looks like:

```
$ zfs get mountpoint,mounted,canmount,overlay rpool -t filesystem -r
NAME               PROPERTY    VALUE                SOURCE
rpool              mountpoint  /                    local
rpool              mounted     no                   -
rpool              canmount    on                   local
rpool              overlay     off                  default
rpool/ROOT         mountpoint  none                 local
rpool/ROOT         mounted     no                   -
rpool/ROOT         canmount    off                  local
rpool/ROOT         overlay     off                  local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  mountpoint  /                    local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  mounted     yes                  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  canmount    noauto               local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  overlay     off                  inherited from rpool/ROOT
rpool/home         mountpoint  /home                inherited from rpool
rpool/home         mounted     no                   -
rpool/home         canmount    on                   default
rpool/home         overlay     off                  default
rpool/home/greg    mountpoint  /home/greg           inherited from rpool
rpool/home/greg    mounted     yes                  -
rpool/home/greg    canmount    on                   default
rpool/home/greg    overlay     off                  default
rpool/home/root    mountpoint  /root                local
rpool/home/root    mounted     no                   -
rpool/home/root    canmount    on                   default
rpool/home/root    overlay     off                  default
rpool/srv          mountpoint  /srv                 inherited from rpool
rpool/srv          mounted     yes                  -
rpool/srv          canmount    on                   default
rpool/srv          overlay     off                  default
rpool/var          mountpoint  /var                 inherited from rpool
rpool/var          mounted     no                   -
rpool/var          canmount    off                  local
rpool/var          overlay     off                  default
rpool/var/cache    mountpoint  /var/cache           inherited from rpool
rpool/var/cache    mounted     yes                  -
rpool/var/cache    canmount    on                   default
rpool/var/cache    overlay     off                  default
rpool/var/games    mountpoint  /var/games           inherited from rpool
rpool/var/games    mounted     yes                  -
rpool/var/games    canmount    on                   default
rpool/var/games    overlay     off                  default
rpool/var/log      mountpoint  legacy               local
rpool/var/log      mounted     yes                  -
rpool/var/log      canmount    on                   default
rpool/var/log      overlay     off                  default
rpool/var/mail     mountpoint  /var/mail            inherited from rpool
rpool/var/mail     mounted     yes                  -
rpool/var/mail     canmount    on                   default
rpool/var/mail     overlay     off                  default
rpool/var/spool    mountpoint  /var/spool           inherited from rpool
rpool/var/spool    mounted     yes                  -
rpool/var/spool    canmount    on                   default
rpool/var/spool    overlay     off                  default
rpool/var/tmp      mountpoint  legacy               local
rpool/var/tmp      mounted     yes                  -
rpool/var/tmp      canmount    on                   default
rpool/var/tmp      overlay     off                  default
```

All my pools are in my zpool list:

```
$ zpool list
NAME         SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
Pool-1tb     976G   414G   562G         -     4%    42%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
Pool-500gb   488G  70.1G   418G         -     0%    14%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
rpool        952G   684G   268G         -    57%    71%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

I'm unable to mount rpool after booting:

```
$ zfs mount rpool
cannot mount '/': directory is not empty
```

Here's the current ZFS related error when I run journalctl -b:
[image]

**Any suggestions on how to get rpool to mount on boot and how to get my system back?**

Running Ubuntu 18.04 with zfsutils-linux 0.7.5 and zfs-dkms 0.7.5

EDIT:

The output of df -h on /

```
$ ls -la
total 174
drwxr-xr-x   26 root root   30 Apr 29 06:58 .
drwxr-xr-x   26 root root   30 Apr 29 06:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root  166 Apr 29 06:56 bin
drwxr-xr-x    4 root root   22 May  5 06:21 boot
drwxr-xr-x   24 root root 5380 May  5 07:22 dev
drwxr-xr-x  154 root root  265 May  5 07:24 etc
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root    3 May  4 12:21 home
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root   33 Apr 29 06:58 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-99-generic
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root   33 Apr 29 06:58 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-96-generic
drwxr-xr-x   24 root root   37 Apr 20 18:58 lib
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   45 Jan 20  2019 lib32
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    3 Jul 10  2019 lib64
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root    3 May  3 01:32 media
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    2 Apr 27  2018 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   13 root root   13 Mar 29 12:34 opt
drwxr-xr-x    5 greg root    5 Apr 23 11:42 Pool-1tb
drwxr-xr-x    6 greg root    6 Apr 21 14:17 Pool-500gb
dr-xr-xr-x 1325 root root    0 May  5 07:21 proc
drwxr-xr-x   11 root root   12 Apr 20 19:27 root
drwxr-xr-x   37 root root 1140 May  5 07:22 run
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root  218 May  2 17:25 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   16 root root   17 Apr 30 13:02 snap
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root    2 Apr 27  2018 srv
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root root    0 May  5 07:21 sys
drwxrwxrwt   20 root root   21 May  5 07:31 tmp
drwx------    4 root root    4 Apr 28  2018 .Trash-0
drwxr-xr-x   12 root root   12 Jul 27  2019 usr
drwxr-xr-x   15 root root   17 Apr 27  2018 var
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root   30 Apr 29 06:58 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-99-generic
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root   30 Apr 29 06:58 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-96-generic
```

The output of ls -la on /home

```
$ ls -la
total 18
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  3 May  4 12:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 30 Apr 29 06:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x 22 greg greg 25 May  5 08:46 greg
```

The output of ls -la on /home/greg

```
$ df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                95G     0   95G   0% /dev
tmpfs               19G  4.6M   19G   1% /run
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  258G   24G  235G  10% /
tmpfs               95G  4.0K   95G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs               95G     0   95G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
rpool/var/log      236G  1.4G  235G   1% /var/log
rpool/var/tmp      235G  128K  235G   1% /var/tmp
/dev/loop0         161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop3          94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop1          94M   94M     0 100% /snap/darktable-kyrofa/49
/dev/loop4         243M  243M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/27
/dev/loop2         141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/loop5         116M  116M     0 100% /snap/checksum-validator/2
/dev/loop6         141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop7         157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop8         2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/730
/dev/loop9          93M   93M     0 100% /snap/darktable-kyrofa/45
/dev/loop10         44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/415
/dev/loop11         94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/8935
/dev/loop12         63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop13        143M  143M     0 100% /snap/slack/23
/dev/loop14        143M  143M     0 100% /snap/slack/22
/dev/loop15         55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop16         62M   62M     0 100% /snap/authy/3
/dev/loop17         55M   55M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
/dev/loop18        9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop19         55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop20        4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/704
Pool-1tb           946G  415G  532G  44% /Pool-1tb
Pool-500gb         473G   71G  403G  15% /Pool-500gb
rpool/srv          235G  128K  235G   1% /srv
rpool/var/games    235G  128K  235G   1% /var/games
rpool/var/mail     235G  128K  235G   1% /var/mail
tmpfs               19G   16K   19G   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs               19G   36K   19G   1% /run/user/1000
```

The output of ls -la on /

```
$ ls -la
ls: cannot access '.gvfs': Permission denied
total 69
drwxr-xr-x 23 greg greg   26 May  5 07:22 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    3 May  4 12:21 ..
-rw-------  1 greg greg 2938 May  5 07:24 .bash_history
drwx------ 18 greg greg   20 May  5 05:57 .cache
drwx------ 17 greg greg   20 May  4 17:49 .config
drwx------  3 root root    3 May  4 13:07 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 Downloads
drwx------  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 .gconf
drwx------  3 greg greg    5 May  4 13:06 .gnupg
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? .gvfs
-rw-------  1 greg greg 2480 May  5 07:22 .ICEauthority
drwx------  3 greg greg    3 May  4 13:04 .local
drwx------  5 greg greg    5 May  4 17:49 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 12:21 NAS
drwx------  3 greg greg    3 May  4 13:04 .nv
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    3 May  5 05:57 Pictures
drwx------  3 greg greg    3 May  4 17:49 .pki
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 Public
drwxr-xr-x  3 greg greg    3 May  4 13:06 snap
drwx------  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:06 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 greg greg    0 May  4 13:07 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 greg greg    2 May  4 13:04 Videos
```

The output of ls -la on /root

```
$ ls -la
total 42
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  12 Apr 20 19:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root  30 Apr 29 06:58 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 399 May  4 12:59 .bash_history
drwx------  4 root root   4 Apr 28  2018 .cache
drwx------  6 root root   6 Jun 23  2018 .config
drwx------  3 root root   3 Apr 28  2018 .dbus
drwx------  2 root root   3 Apr 20 20:01 .ecryptfs
drwx------  2 root root   2 Nov  8  2018 .gconf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   3 May  5 07:21 .hplip
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   3 Apr 28  2018 .local
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   3 Mar 29 19:01 snap
drwx------  3 root root   6 May  5 06:24 .synaptic
```

The output of ls -la on /var/cache

```
$ ls -la
total 142
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root  19 Feb 18 06:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  17 Apr 27  2018 ..
drwx------  2 root root  22 Apr 30 13:02 apparmor
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4 Dec  6  2018 app-info
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   5 May  5 06:21 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   6 Apr 29  2018 cracklib
drwxrwx---  3 root lp    11 May  5 06:31 cups
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   7 May  5 06:21 debconf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 153 Apr 30 13:02 fontconfig
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4 May  4 13:05 fwupd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   2 Jun  5  2018 gdm
drwx------  2 root root   3 May  2 17:26 ldconfig
drwxr-xr-x 35 man  man   37 May  5 06:21 man
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 227 May  5 05:28 motd-news
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   3 Sep  3  2018 PackageKit
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   5 May  5 07:22 samba
drwx------  2 root root   2 Aug 30  2016 slack
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   6 May  4 15:28 snapd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   3 Apr 29  2018 ubuntu-advantage-tools
```

The output of ls -la on /var/spool

```
$ ls -la
total 11
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root  5 May  4 12:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root 17 Apr 27  2018 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root  3 May  4 12:26 cron
drwx--x---  3 root   lp    3 May  4 12:26 cups
drwx------  2 syslog adm   2 May  4 12:21 rsyslog
```

Comment: Apparently you are trying to mount zfs on mountpoints (directories) that are not empty. After booting with the error, what is the output of `df -h` and what are the content of /, /home, /home/greg, /root, /var/cache and /var/spool ? Do an `ls -la` on each of them, and update your question with the results - basically we just need to see if each directory contains files or not (except from `.` and `..`).

Comment: @SorenA I've updated my post with the information you requested.

Comment: It looks like the right zfs volumes are mounted. What are the content of /etc/fstab ?

Comment: @SorenA I have the contents of fstab listed above. (second code snippet from the top)

Comment: @SorenA if you look at the output for "zfs get mountpoint,canmount,mounted rpool -t filesystem -r" it says that rpool is not mounted. (third snippet down from the top)

Comment: rpool and rpool/ROOT/ubuntu  has same mountpoint `/` , so only one can be mounted. If it was my system,I would boot it in rescue mode (single user mode) unmount everything execpt from /. Then work through each mount, verifying every mountpoint directory IS empty. If not,fix it, and mount that one ... and so on. And start by making a good backup, if you end up deleting something needed. and verify that you can restore from it, before you need it.

Comment: @SorenA Thanks for the idea! I was able to delete the home folder in my active session, and then link my ZFS home folder with a legacy mount, and turned canmount off for everything else (since a lot of those folders were causing errors on boot anyway). Everything appears to be working for now, but if I have any problems I'll probably end up doing what you suggested. I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the redundant, unused `mountpoint` attribute from the datasets. If `rpool` (the root dataset) is actually unused, remove the `mountpoint` attribute and set it on the dataset actually used (`rpool/ROOT/ubuntu`):

```
zfs set mountpoint=none rpool
```

And the most important, you **should** set the `rootfs` zpool attribute in addition to set the `mountpoint=/` at the dataset level:

```
zpool set bootfs=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu rpool
```

Also, is safe to delete the mountpoint directories (ZFS will create them when mounting). Please rename or backup those directories.

If you don't have a rescue disk, you may get the Busybox shell by appending `init=/bin/Busybox sh` and remove the `root=` argument in the boot command line arguments. Then, you may import the pool without mounting (`zpool import -R /mnt -n rpool`), then, edit the attributes as you need.

Finally, **never** rely on fstab for mounting zfs *filesystem* datasets (except for zvols like `swap`), unless you're know what you doing, as datasets with standard `mountpoint` attribute are mounted early. Use `mountpoint=legacy` to allow be mounted using `mount` or trough `fstab`.