Problem mounting ZFS Pool on root
My problem is that /root/ is pretended before the path set in the ZFS pool.
I already set the mountpoint for the root of the pool and the ROOT Dataset to none as described here https://askubuntu.com/a/1238042
I also did set the zpool set bootfs but this didn't changed anything.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.10

    3.673166] ZFS: Loaded module v2.2.6-1ubuntu1, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5 : Importing ZFS root pool zrpool' Begin: Importing pool 'zrpool' using defaults... done.
    
    Begin done.
    
    Mounting 'zrpool/R00T/ubuntu_bc9z17' on '/root//... done. Mounting 'zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/srv on /root//srv
    
    Begin:
    
    Begin: Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/R00T/ubuntu_bc9z17/usr on /root//usr... done.
    
    done.
    
    Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/R00T/ubuntu_bc9z17/usr/local' on /root//usr/local' Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var on /root//var... done.
    
    done.
    
    Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/R00T/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/games on /root//var/games zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/lib' on /root//var/lib'. done.
    
    ... done.
    
    done.
    
    Begin: Begin: zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/lib/AccountsService on /root//var/lib/AccountsService Mounting 'zrpool/R00T/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/lib/Network Manager on /root//var/lib/NetworkManager'
    
    ing Mounting '
    
    Begin: Mount done.
    
    done.
    
    Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/R00T/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/lib/apt on /root//var/lib/apt. done. root//var/lib/dpkg..
    
    Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/lib/dpkg on / Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/R00T/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/log' on /root//var/log... done. ' on /root//var/mail... done.
    
    Begin: Mount ing zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/mail zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/snap' on /root//var/snap... done. done.
    
    Begin: Mounting zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/spool on /root//var/spool'.
    
    Begin: Mounting Begin: Mounting 'zrpool/ROOT/ubuntu_bc9z17/var/www on /root//var/www done.
    
    Begin: Running/scripts/local-bottom done.
    
    done. .. done.
    
    Begin : Running/scripts/nfs-bottom Begin: Running/scripts/init-bottom done.
    
    run-init: can't execute /sbin/init': No such file or directory
    
    Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
    
    run-init: can't execute /sbin/init': No such file or directory run-init: can't execute /etc/init': Permission denied

